# Xlib and scrolling

Tags: x11, xlib

I don't how to deal with scrolling a list of 1000 windows.  I have 1000 windows in a column. The column is higher than the window, because every window in the list is 40 pixels high, so the column is 40000 pixels high.

I tried 2 things.

1. I changed the Y position of each one of them and move them with `XMoveWindow`, I do it slower than 16ms and get some blinking.  All in all it's not a scalable solution.  So it doesn't work.
2. I made a window which is 40000 pixels high, but if I move it Xlib raises and error `BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)`.

There is an Xlib manual with an example of scrolling some text in a window.  You draw text into the pixmap and copy the `Pixmap` to the `Window` with `XCopyArea` from a certain point when you scroll the text.  Again I don't really understand how to handle a big chunk of text, because you can't create a big `Pixmap`.

How can I scroll 1000 windows?  An idea with references to Xlib functions or even a code snippet in C/D/Rust/Python/C++/Go/Java are appreciated.

Comment: Track which ones are visible and which are not. When a window becomes unviewable, unmap it; when it is viewable again, map it back.

Comment: Also double buffering may help. Keep two copies of the parent window complete with its own set of children. When you need to scroll, move the children of the unmapped window, then map it and unmap the previously mapped one.

Comment: @n.m. That's brilliant.  I should've guessed.  So, to be for clear for those who look at the question.  I do XUnmapWindow and do XMoveWindow for those which are in the parent window boundary.  The CPU consumption still a bit high, but it least no blinks.  I think it can be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[n. m. could be an AI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m-could-be-an-ai) answered my question in comments.  Mapping those buttons which are visible and unmapping the rest of them works just fine for 1000 buttons.  The CPU load was close to 1%, the consumed memory wasn't that high.  Below 4MB.  I guess that the memory was allocated for the process Xorg.

But I found myself drawing about 25000 buttons.  And all of them are visible.  I have rows of buttons.  It's actually a Flame Graph if it helps.  It took a couple of seconds, which doesn't work for me.  For this case the answer from [Erdal Küçük](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11867590/erdal-k%C3%BC%C3%A7%C3%BCk) worked.  One clarification. Finding a button under the cursor in my case was pretty simple because:

1. Every button has the same height (H), so to find the row of the buttons was O(1).  I divided the X coordinate of the mouse cursor by H.  It gives the number of row with the button.
2. I had an array where the buttons are placed sorted by X coordinate.  So the buttons were sorted in rows automatically.  I use the Binary Search so it takes O(log(n)).

Works fast enough, even for hover events (when the mouse is over a button).  The CPU utilization barely gets to 1%.

Answer (score 1):

The resources are always limited. You cannot create a 'gigantic' pixmap, but what you can do is to create a 'myriad' of smaller pixmaps.

Render all your data into single pixmaps (one pixmap for every item) and store them in a list. Based on your scroll position, only the relevant pixmaps are blit into the window.

As an example, if your pixmaps have a fixed height (in your case 40px) and the scroll position is `90`, then `90/40 = 2`, that means you start rendering with the pixmap at index `2` at the y-position `-10` and you render only that many pixmaps, that would fit into the window.

Only one window required, no frequent mapping and unmapping and no window move requests on each and every scroll event.

The only downside is, that key and pointer events have to be handled in a different way.

---

How to handle key and pointer events:

If you receive those events on your window, simply calculate (again based on the scroll position) which item is affected (remember, the xevents do contain the x and y coordinates - in case of an key event, you'll have to remember which item is selected, so you have to keep track of the item, that was picked at the last event).

I don't know if this inconvenience justifies the management of hundreds (thousands) of 'unused' windows and the respective round trips to the server.

Comment: This is point, I need those windows to handle pointer events.  Xlib can handle them.  Taking that into account, can I use the solution is moving and mapping?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it might give you more insight.

Comment: _"can I use the solution is moving and mapping"_ of course you can, the question you should ask yourself, why you prefer that solution over the other. Why produce unnecessary noise on the ether (and server), if some simple calculations on the client side will do.

Comment: I didn't get.  What noise are you talking about?  I decided to make windows instead of handling clicking on my own, because Xlib does it.  But now you are talking about the noise and I feel like I hadn't taken something into account.

Comment: A window is an _heavy weight_ object. The window manager and the xserver have to take all the (thousand) windows into account. Which in my opinion is unnecessary and every additional (unnecessary) processed information, i call noise.

Comment: Let me clarify, please.  Are you talking memory consumption?  It is barely grows after initializing those 1000 windows.  The application consumes additional 2-4KB or so (~3.5MB RSS in total.)  The Xorg process doesn't consume anything extra.  I agree it's huge amount of memory at some cases, but not in mine.  It's fine even the application will take additional 15MB RSS.  Let me know if you mean something else, I'd rather would like to get the clear picture.

Comment: Not only memory (which imho is the least concern), but if you have a window manager then the wm wants to know, what happens to each and every single window. There is a lot of ('hidden') communication going on behind the curtains. The more windows, the more 'chatter' (noise, which could manifest in flickering, lag, etc.). If you use only one single window, then there is not much to talk about and can be handled very easily.

Comment: Look, all you need is the scroll position, based on that you simply blit a few pixmaps onto the screen, otherwise, not only will the windows get managed by the xserver and the wm, but you want frequently map and unmap them and update their positions (which generates a lot of events in the background, even if you're not interested in those events, the wm or any internals of the server might).